# Will SSL passthrough cause all traffic on the backend server to appear to originate from the load balancer?

Tags: ssl, load-balancing, tcp

When using a load balancer I understand that using SSL termination will result in the backend server seeing all connections as originating from the load balancer itself.  I'm not sure however if the same is true with SSL passthrough.  Since SSL passthrough operates at the TCP layer would it still see the actual originating IP address on the backend server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what exactly your "load balancer" does.

If your load balancer is operating as a form of router then the servers will see the real client IPs.

OTOH if your load balacer is terminating one TCP connection and passing the traffic off to another TCP connection then the backend servers will see the load balancers IP.